# Store jquery next selector in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to store the jQuery `next()` and `prev()` selectors in a variable like this:

```
var direction = 'next()';
$('#element').direction.remove();
```

I tried the above and it's not working. Is it possible to do it?